# How to check the 302 redirect history of a domain via Mac Terminal or CMD

Tags: redirect, dns, history

I was buying a domain and I need to verify the history of the domain in-terms of 302 redirects on the domains. is there any way by which I can check a domains history in CMD or Terminal in mac.
So, that it will mention one by one that it is redirected to some other domain or not in it's past history